# How to find the range of values using the SQL query where the string is constant and the number is variable

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a primary key in my table something like "abc.001 to abc.100" and "xyz.1000 to xyz.2000". So, there is a range of variable numbers but constant String value. Now, if I wanted to find the particular range between abc.011 to abc.020 then what query should I supposed to use. I tried using the between clause but it returns the last result in the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer using the regexp_like. I made the query something like this,
`select * from orders where REGEXP_LIKE (order_id, '^abc.(\d{1}|\d{2})$');`
This query returns the results from 0-99 however if I need the result until 0-100 then I tried to use the third criteria 
`select * from orders where REGEXP_LIKE (order_id, '^abc.(\d{1}|\d{2}|\d{3})$');`
The above query returns the result until 999 but I am in search of only until 100. I still need to find the accurate query for that.

Answer (score 0):

Will the string bit be constant? If so you can substring (SUBSTR()) the primary key to just take the number part, to_number it and then filter by that.

e.g.

```
select *
from table
where to_number(substr(col,5,3)) between 1 and 100
```

If you want to use the characters for comparison as well you'll have to do something more fancy like convert them to ascii values one at a time and filter by that e.g.

```
select ascii('y') from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not have strings in your primary keys for this exact reason.
I suggest making another field called letter_prefix and have it indexed. A proper query for this situation should look like:

```
SELECT * FROM table t WHERE t.letter_prefix='abc' and t.pk BETWEEN minVal and maxVal;
```

One approach to your problem is using substring functions:

```
SELECT * FROM test_table t WHERE substring(t.pk, 1, 3) = 'abc' and substring(t.pk, 5, 7) BETWEEN 0 AND 100;
```

Comment: I used the query like this, SELECT * FROM orders t WHERE t.order_id = 'abc.' and t.order_id BETWEEN 1 and 100; This doesn't return any row. Note: value abc is constant and some of the numbers are not occupied in the range, such as abc.22, abc.55, abc.81 etc. But I wanted to know the whole range and find out which are not occupied.

Comment: If your primary key is a string of characters (varchar2 or something like that) in the format of 'abc.123' the first clause of your where fails, as the t.order_id IS NOT EQUAL to 'abc'.